# Does the Hapi.js websocket protocol communication need to use hapi.js for the client to connect to the websocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, hapi.js, nes

I am building an API using Hapi. I need WebSocket functionality and it seems that Nes is the most popular to be used with Hapi. This is fine since Nes makes things quite easy, for example, a test route might look as so...

```
// Register Nes.
await server.register(Nes);
...
...
// WebSocket route.
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/h',
  config: {
    id: 'hello',
    handler: (request, h) => {
      return 'world!';
    }
  }
});
```

This is great, however, the documentation shows that the only way to make a request to this route using WebSockets is by using Nes on the client as well...

```
const Nes = require('nes');

var client = new Nes.Client('ws://localhost');

const start = async () => {

  await client.connect();
  const payload = await client.request('hello');  // Can also request '/h'
  // payload -> 'world!'
};

start();
```

My issue is that the client does not use JavaScript. The Nes library does not exist at all. In that case, can I still use WebSockets to make a request to this route? There are no examples of this so I do not understand how I could do so. If it is not possible, then I would like to know what my options are as even Socket.io does not exist in the framework I am using (Flutter).

Comment: this question and your way of framing it are very confusing. The client doesn't need to use NES to communicate with the websocket

Comment: curious if you ever figured this out? same setup. hapi + flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WebSockets are just a [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), any WebSocket client library for flutter should work. WebSockets are not tied directly to a specific language. Thus, you have to find and implement a WebSocket library for your framework. I browsed their website and found a few potential candidates, though I'm sure it's not an exhaustive list.

Here are some potential web socket packages from Flutter:

- [Socket.io](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_socket_io)
- [Dart HTTP](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/w_transport)

For information on integrating the package, check out [this link](https://flutter.io/using-packages/) here.

As for developing web sockets with Hapi, you don't *have* to use [NES](https://github.com/hapijs/nes). It may make the most sense to use a library, like [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) that is developed by the same publisher for both the client and server. While using Socket.io with Hapi is beyond the scope of this answer, you may find [this medium article](https://matt-harrison.com/posts/hapi-socket-io/) helpful.